# how does gdb attach to multithread process

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, gdb, ptrace

When we use `gdb attach` to debug a running process, we could use `gdb attach pid` ,if the process have two or more threads, the pid is the main thread tid.


Now I want to implement a simple debugger to debug multi-thread process, but when I use my debugger to attach a multi-thread process, only the `main thread` suspended.


I want to know why only use the main thread tid, the `gdb` can attach all thread of this process, how does gdb suspend all the threads? we assume that when we use `gdb attach`, all the thread have been created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to know why only use the main thread tid, the gdb can attach all thread of this process, how does gdb suspend all the threads?

When you do `attach PROCESS_PID` `gdb` internally calls ptrace (PTRACE_ATTACH) **for each thread**. on Linux you can check it yourself with:

```
$ strace -e ptrace -p GDB_PROCESS_PID
```

Just run a program with s few threads, run gdb and before running attach PROCESS_PID run strace in another console. You must see ptrace (PTRACE_ATTACH) for each thread.

Answer (score 2):

ptrace `PTRACE_ATTACH` sends `SIGSTOP` to the process which suspends the whole process i.e. all threads.

Answer (score 0):

The main thread TID having the same numerical value as the process PID is a historical accident of Linux systems; it isn't the case on other Unix systems.

When gdb (or any debugger) attaches to a process using ptrace, all the threads of that process are suspended.

Comment: I know the gdb use 'ptrace' to implement attach function, but how to use 'ptrace' to suspend all the threads. I can only make  the thread suspended which TID is the same with PID .

Comment: @wangxf all the threads are suspended when gdb attaches to a process. Do you have some example where this is not the case?

Comment: Actually, I want to implement a simple debugger, but I do not know how to make all the threads suspended when my debugger attache to a process, I can only make the main thread suspend.